# Where is the notion of .data(xx.map(function(d))...) defined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Sorry for the vague title (I will update it later, and I'll update tags too).  In some code I am trying to understand, I found the following:

```
var map = svg.append("svg")
.attr({x: 10,
       y: 10)
.selectAll("path")
.data(cl.map(function(d) { // ????
        return d3.range(d.x.length).map(function(i) {
    return {x: d.x[i], y: d.y[i]};});}))
.enter().append("svg:path")
.attr("d", lineMap)
.style("fill", "none")
.style("stroke", "darkgreen")
    .style("stroke-width", 1);
```

`cl` is a set of contour lines data to be connected up as a path.  My question is about the part I marked ????.  I understand what this does in general terms, and even the details.  Since I'm new to this stuff, I'm wondering where the `.data` and `.map` ideas are documented, and to what language they belong (JavaScript? JSON?).  I've looked around and it's a bit tough to find answers when googling 'map data'!  Also, is the d notion that seems to be in most JavaScript functions a required name?  Or just the custom?

Comment: The language is javascript and the `data` and `map` functions are some of d3.js own.  You can find out more about them in the api documentation, [here for data](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) and [here for map](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#nest_map). The `data` function joins the data to the selected elements in that were generated by the selectAll call.  The `map`function nests the data into the form that you need, in this case something that the line function is expecting.

Comment: Thank you very much @user1614080. I had seen `nest.map` but was thrown off by the `nest` part - I didn't think it applied more generically.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @user1614080 In the code in the question, it's actually Javascript's `.map()`. `d3.range()` returns a normal Javascript array and `cl`, from OP's description, is as well.

Comment: @Lars Right you are, I actually thought the OP was doing something like this `d3.nest.key(function(d) { return d.some_names; }).entries(some_array);`.  Which the OP wasn't, although you could use something this to generate the data for the line function.

Comment: OP here.  After reading up on all these great links, I see that `nest` is basically used to subset & order/sort existing data. My example did not require that because my data was passed in ready to go: an array of arrays with x and y labels, [...],[...],...] so then `nest` is not needed, and the nested `map` anonymous function makes perfect sense in how it will iterate over the full data set.  Thanks to all.  The link to alignedleft.com was very helpful in explaining this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of pointers:

`.map` is a javascript array function (note that d3.arrays also have a map function) that return a new array with the result of calling the callback function for each element in the original array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

`.data` is a d3 concept and is the way to bind a data set to a selection

http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

Hope this helps.